# How i fill my content layout with fragment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, layout

i need some help.

I have a CoordinatorLayout in my content layout and RelativeLayout in my fragment, but i want fill whole space with the fragment layout.
Someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Post your xml file if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have some margins in your activity layout

Answer (score 0):

I guess on your `xml` you have something like this :

```
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

Just remove those paddings and your `FragmentLayout` will be filled.